# Convert lstart to mysql timestamp

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a bash script that gets the time a process started with `ps lstart`. So something like `Thu Jul 29 14:48:08 2021`.

I would like to insert it into a mysql column of type `timestamp`.
I have tried to convert the lstart value like

```
timestamp=`date -d "${lstart}" +"%s"`
```

but when trying to insert in the table the script complains that

```
incorrect datetime value: '1627570088' for column
```

I can change the type from timestamp to another if it is the correct way.

The idea of this column is to use it to remove all rows with a start date older than a given datetime.

Comment: You will want to wrap that Unix timestamp with `FROM_UNIXTIME()`, which will allow you to record the data.

Comment: Try something like `timestamp="$(date -d "$lstart" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"`